Getting AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy.core.arrayprint' has no attribute 'array2string' (most likely due to circular import) eror
I tried installing pandarallel but couldn't install due to some errors. Now when I try to simply import pandas and numpy, I am getting error:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'numpy.core.arrayprint' has no attribute 'array2string' (most likely due to circular import)

I am getting it if I try to import either pandas or numpy. I looked up other answers to similar partially initialied module errors, tried renaming numpy file, but it's still not fixing the issue.
I tried upgrading numpy using pip, still it didn't help.
Can someone please help me with this error.

The Error you are encountering is likely due to a conflict or corruption in your python environment. Make sure you don't have files with name numpy.py or pandas.py. These files might be causing circular imports. if not and uninstalling then reinstalling them also not resolves your issue then check the installation path of pandas and numpy. if the issue still persists, it may be best to start with a fresh virtual environment.

@RajaJahanzaib, there a single numpy.py file in the C:/Python311/Lib/site-packages/optree/integration folder that's created on the day I started getting this issue. I renamed it to numpy11.py. still the error persists.  Can you please let me know if I need to look elsewhere too?

python compiles .py files into .pyc files for performance. Even after renaming the numpy.py file, the .pyc file might still cause the error navigate to the folder where you renamed the numpy.py file look for .pyc file there like numpy.cpython-311.pyc and delete it also. if still issue persists then check the exact file path being imported when you try to import numpy
import numpy print(numpy.__file__)

@RajaJahanzaib, deleted the files, but still didn't work, now trying to uninstall and reinstall again!

Is your file path points to C:/Python311/Lib/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py when importing?

The optree library appears to have created a numpy.py file. It's possible other packages have done something similar. Search your site-packages folder for files named numpy.py using this command find C:/Python311/Lib/site-packages -name "numpy.py"  and check that there is only single file exists.
If still persists then reinstall optree  and recreate the virtual environment.
NOTE: Are you doing same for pandas also as you have mentioned its also creating issue and also check is error changed or still same error you encountered initially.

@RajaJahanzaib, I couldn't run the import numpy print(numpy.__file__) command as it gave it same error. But when I tried to upgrade numpy, it said requirement satisfied and pointed to C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Python...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You have installed numpy in your local environment eg. C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Python... which is conflicting with the global installation in C:/Python311/Lib/site-packages/numpy/__init.py__. This conflict is causing Python to load the wrong version or a corrupted version of numpy. To fix this you have to remove/uninstall it from local env and reinstall it with admin previliges to ensure a clean installation, either by using python -m pip install numpy in an admin command prompt or installing it globally.This resolves conflicts and ensures Python uses the correct version of numpy.
